# Send params on refresh token using acquireTokenSilent

Tags: angular, msal-angular, msal

we are using msal to handle the authentication in our angular application (v12). We have a specific use case where we need to pass a parameter to the token generator service in order to get the correct user account, and when we make the inital request to get the token, it works, using the *tokenQueryParameters* parameter we are able to send such parameter:

[image: using acquireTokenSilent funcition]

[image: request]

But on refresh token, as is handled automatically on token expiration, the parameter is not sent anymore.

[image: request sent on token expiration]

Is there a way to send the same parameter in the refresh token request? Thank you.